# Confusion about Newton's first law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

At the lowest point on a ramp, the skateboarder is travelling at a constant speed along a path which is part of a vertical circle.
How does the weight of the skateboarder compare with the upward force that the ramp exerts on her?
Since the skater is moving at a constant speed wont the weight be equal in magnitude? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Newton's first law doesn't talk about a body moving at constant *speed*, but about a body moving at constant *velocity*. Your skateboarder, travelling on a curved path, does not have a constant velocity, and must therefore be acted upon by a resultant force.

Answer (score 1):

In a uniform circular motion, we have that the speed is constant but not the vector velocity, so the resultant force is not 0.

The sum of the normal force with the weight needs to be equal to $\frac{1}{R} mv^2 $ so we have:

$$N - W = \frac{1}{R} mv^2 $$